# Cannot execute EF Core migration on remote Azure SQL Server database - No such host is known

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework-core

I try to execute migration on remote, Azure SQL Server database.

Command:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ./../Teamdare.Bot database update -e Production
```

Connection string in `appsettings.Production.json`:

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=tcp:project.database.windows.net,1433;Database=project;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=login@project;Password=projectPassword;"
```

The migrations work for local database and database credentials are correct as well - they work with previous app and by db GUI client.

The error:

> One or more errors occurred. (No such host is known)

I tried some variations of connection string, this one seem to be most similar to one provided here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/

Comment: Have you tried the connection string provided directly through azure portal? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet

Comment: Yes, I did, but it generates even more errors as EF Core doesn't understand some keywords in this connection string.

Comment: Sample: `Keyword not supported: initial catalog Parameter name: keyword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing was I was using wrong handler - I stayed with the one used for PostgreSQL database, which we use for local developement.

Comment: What handler do you mean?